# id passed from url, but i need to get country and other info from sql for this id (specific `id`)

Tags: php, sql, get

in line `$id = $_GET['id'];` id passed from url, but i need to get country  and other info from sql
(data base) for this id, how correctly get country and other info from
sql for specific `id`, only `"id"` displays correctly in both cases.

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `list`  ORDER BY category ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);      
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    echo $id;
    echo $country;  
?>
```

and

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `list`  ORDER BY category ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $id;
            echo $country;  
        }
    } 
?>
```

maybe I do something wrong, are new in PHP

Comment: You posted the same question "how" many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<?php
//please use filter_input instead of $_GET
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE id='$id' ORDER BY category ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $rows['id'];
        echo $rows['country'];  
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: That way i think you'll pass string $id to database ... try to switch it to `id='.$id.'` so you pass variable value

Comment: if you use quotation marks then you can add variable to string.

Comment: @kotapeter this method works, thanks!

Comment: Nice job @kotapeter. Thx for helping him :)

Comment: I should not have to help him?